# GroovyShell in OSGi environment

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, osgi

The goal is to run simple script using `GroovyShell` in an Eclipse plugin. Purpose of the script is to get some info about the workspace. Groovy itself is embedded into Eclipse in form of an OSGi plugin built from `groovy-all-xxx.jar`. The plugin containing the script has dependencies (among others) to `org.eclipse.core.runtime` and `org.eclipse.core.resources`.

Part of the code executing the script:

```java
Map<String, Object> varmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
varmap.put("workspace", ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace());
Binding binding = new Binding(varmap);
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()), binding);
System.out.println(shell.evaluate("return workspace.getRoot().getProject(\"abc\").getName()"));
```

This gets me:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
[Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPluginPrerequisite
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPluginPrerequisite 
cannot be found by org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.301.v20130717-1549
```

(full stack [here](http://pastebin.com/HRRG5hEg))

Note that everything works fine when those workspace operations are called from plain Java code.

I guess that might be caused by E4's DI feature using it's own classloader. But what makes the difference causing the code not to be running inside the GroovyShell?

Anyone?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but Eclipse plugins will only run in Eclipse.

Comment: The code is part of an Eclipse plugin

Comment: For those interested I think it's related to this: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2980. Thought that using Groovy libs with invokedynamic enabled might help, but no luck.